# Error message in check-update regarding httpd

Tags: cron, apache-httpd, oracle-linux

I am using Oracle Linux 9. I have installed Apache server by this module: mod_h264_streaming-2.2.7-17.fc37.x86_64.rpm

Also, I need three repositories EPEL, raven and remi repo.
The problem is, when I run: */etc/cron.daily/chk-update*
I receive this Error message:

```
Error: 
 Problem 1: package httpd-core-2.4.53-7.0.1.el9.x86_64 requires httpd-filesystem = 2.4.53-7.0.1.el9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both httpd-filesystem-2.4.54-1.el9.noarch and httpd-filesystem-2.4.53-7.0.1.el9.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package httpd-filesystem-2.4.53-7.0.1.el9.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package httpd-core-2.4.53-7.0.1.el9.x86_64
 
Problem 2: problem with installed package httpd-core-2.4.53-7.0.1.el9.x86_64
  - package httpd-core-2.4.53-7.0.1.el9.x86_64 requires httpd-tools = 2.4.53-7.0.1.el9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both httpd-tools-2.4.54-1.el9.x86_64 and httpd-tools-2.4.53-7.0.1.el9.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package httpd-tools-2.4.53-7.0.1.el9.x86_64
```

I suppose the error message has to do with the mix of the repositories. The solution to this, is to run: *dnf update --best --allowerasing* and the message will not appear again. But, my problem is that I would like to prevent this message from appearing. How can I prevent this from happening? Is there a way to install Apache and keep all these repositories at the same time, but without the error message?